# Are the UTC datetime formats acknowledged by W3C identical to those of ISO 8601?

Tags: datetime, datetime-format, utc, w3c, iso8601

The W3C [Date and Time note](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) suggests that date and time 'official' formats are identical to, or a subset of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The note says "This document defines a profile of ISO 8601", and also "To reduce the scope for error and the complexity of software, it is useful to restrict the supported formats to a small number."

Is it safe to assume, that all W3C datetimes (such as those used in server logs) are therefore compatible with ISO 8601?

Comment: I think that the W3C page you are linking to pretty explicitly says that the formats mentioned are *not* acknowledged by W3C?

Comment: Are they not? I only see the "A particular problem with ISO 8601 is that", part

Comment: Quote: “This document is a NOTE made available by the W3 Consortium for discussion only. This indicates no endorsement of its content, nor that the Consortium has, is, or will be allocating any resources to the issues addressed by the NOTE.”

Comment: FWIW, I had trouble understanding what "all W3C datetimes" might refer to. And, given that you mention "server logs", I'm not sure why you think whatever server you're interested in would follow a W3C recomendation for date/time formatting of its logs...